# What's a natural substitute for baking powder or baking soda?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry, food-chemistry

What's a natural substitute for baking power or baking soda? I am doing a project where I need a raising agent in liquid form. Naturally, I can't use anything carbonated so baking powder/soda are out of question.

Comment: Yeast? It causes bread to rise.

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more, what you are trying to accomplish? For example: What ingredients do you use, what is the purpose, should it be eatable, are you applying heat?

Comment: The three sentences in your question seem completely unrelated. Why would does requiring that your ingredient be 'natural' (whatever that means) imply that you can't use baking soda, or that it be liquid, or that it can't be carbonated?

Answer (score 2):

I never heard about chemical rising agent in liquid form. You can use [monocalcium phosphate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monocalcium_phosphate) that was an ancient leavening agent.

[image]

But maybe you should follow the advice of Dissenter and use yogurt, [Sourdough Starter](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Sourdough_Starter) or [Kefir](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Kefir) all these produce carbon dioxide through fermentation, and are more "natural".

You can look at [this wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Cookbook:Leavening_Agent) for a list of leavening agent.

Answer (score 0):

Carbonate is very natural.  Wood ash has a significant amount of potassium and sodium carbonate.  You can see this by collecting white powdery wood ash and adding vinegar.

Rock formations like limestone naturally contain carbonate, although limestone is calcium carbonate.

Comment: While this is all correct and true, the OP is asking for a substitute.